What could prevent iSCSI disk to mount on Ubuntu?
I'm trying to mount iSCSI volume inside a VM running on Proxmox PVE. It gets stuck somewhere in the middle of the process and I exhausted all obvious avenues so far.
Environment:

iSCSI server is Synology NAS. Configured to allow initiators without any authentication to attach to a LUN. I can use it from desktop which runs arch with 6.9.7 kernel and iscsiadm version 2.1.10. When I connect to it, NAS shows there's an active connection to the LUN.
Client: VM (KVM) running in Proxmox PVE, uses LAN IP addresses on the same subnet as NAS. Runs Ubuntu 24.04 LTS with 6.8.0 kernel and iscsiadm version 2.1.9. Network works both ways between VMs and hosts on LAN.

I attach the drive using:
sudo iscsiadm --mode node --targetname <my.nas.target> --portal <nas.address> --login

On the arch host this command results in:
❯❯❯ sudo iscsiadm -m session -P 3
iSCSI Transport Class version 2.0-870
version 2.1.10
Target: <my.nas.target> (non-flash)
    Current Portal: <portal.ip>:3260,1
    Persistent Portal: <portal.ip>:3260,1
        **********
        Interface:
        **********
...
        ************************
        Attached SCSI devices:
        ************************
        Host Number: 7  State: running
        scsi7 Channel 00 Id 0 Lun: 1
            Attached scsi disk sdg      State: running

in logs I see:
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> iscsid[242074]: iscsid: Connection3:0 to [target: <my.nas.target>, portal: <portal.ip>,3260] through [iface: default] is operational now
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: scsi 7:0:0:1: Direct-Access     SYNOLOGY Storage          4.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] 629145600 512-byte logical blocks: (322 GB/300 GiB)
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Write Protect is off
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Mode Sense: 43 00 10 08
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, supports DPO and FUA
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Preferred minimum I/O size 512 bytes
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Optimal transfer size 16384 logical blocks > dev_max (8192 logical blocks)
Nov 24 16:35:18 <arch> kernel: sd 7:0:0:1: [sdg] Attached SCSI disk

and the drive could be mounted using mount -t ext4 /dev/sdg /mnt/storage.
While on Ubuntu VM it ends up like:
ali@ubuntu:~$ sudo iscsiadm -m session -P 3 
iSCSI Transport Class version 2.0-870
version 2.1.9
Target: <my.nas.target> (non-flash)
    Current Portal: <portal.ip>:3260,1
    Persistent Portal: <portal.ip>:3260,1
        **********
        Interface:
        **********
...
        ************************
        Attached SCSI devices:
        ************************
        Host Number: 3  State: running

In logs for VM i can see:
Nov 24 16:41:30 <vm> iscsid[875]: Could not set session3 priority. READ/WRITE throughout and latency could be affected.
Nov 24 16:41:30 <vm> iscsid[875]: Connection3:0 to [target: <my.nas.target>, portal: <portal.ip>,3260] through [iface: default] is operational now

and no device is created so volume can't be mounted. At the same time NAS reports that there's a connection to the LUN from the VM's initiator. I can also see that iscsid creates a connection to the NAS's iscsi port in both cases.
So it looks like iscsi part works, but then it doesn't trigger creation of disk device.

Start by restarting the iscsid service and ensure it's running properly. It's also important to check that your kernel is up to date, as compatibility issues can arise with older versions. After restarting the service, log out and log back in to ensure that the iSCSI session is properly established. Use the dmesg command to look for any errors related to device discovery, as this can provide insights into why the disk isn't being created. Additionally, verify that the correct permissions and udev rules are in place on the VM to allow device creation. Lastly, review the iSCSI configuration on your NAS and restart the iSCSI service there to ensure it's properly set up to allow connections.

I narrowed that down to:

does not work on 22.04 LTS in VMs
works on 24.10 in VMs

Don't have older kernel on physical machines to test.
Did testing with fresh installs. Installing newer versions of iscsi on older distributions also seem excessive pain and won't resolve immediate issue for me.
It is likely that the cause is some compatibility issue with 6.8.x kernel Ubuntu LTS uses with Synology iscsi which was fixed in later (6.9.x) kernels or open-iscsi.
